# Is it possible to setup a VPN that passes multiple ports through a single port tunnel?

Tags: networking, vpn, linux-networking, openvpn, port

I am looking to set up a VPN (possibly OpenVPN) to allow a computer connected to the internet through a restricted university network to connect to the wider internet through my home network.

My specifically, I would like it to be able to use multiple of its ports, ie 80, 8081, 4123 etc. The network it is attached to only allows for port 80 (and possibly a few other specific ones) to connect to the internet. Preferably the ports would get combined on the university side through software running on the machine itself (saving another pi or similar), and on the home side split through a raspberry pi running the VPN server. Would this be possible using a VPN like OpenVPN? Please let me know if you need any further clarification.

For record all the machines involved would be running Linux. Debian-based specifically for the machine on the university side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's pretty much what a VPN does - tunnels multiple connections through a single connection. There's no end of tool available to do this - including openvpn. However openvpn requires you to provision certificates - which can be a bit tricky.

However....

In order to connect to the other end, the other end must be exposed and have a known address. Most "home" internet connections will use a single dynamically assigned address with NAT (in the form of masquerading) to allow the hosts on the LAN to connect out to the internet. That's 2 problems you need to solve.

If you don't have a static address, then the easiest solution is to use a dynamic DNS service. A machine in you home LAN regularly updates a public DNS service with the public IP its using. Some ISP routers have this capability built-in - which  means that the DNS data can be updated *when the IP address changes*.

For the second problem, you'll need to enable port forwarding on your rouer to allow the inward connection to the openvpn server.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your response. Don't worry, I understand about port forwarding and public ips, our home ip isn't static but changed infrequently enough (maybe once a year) that I can edit the DNS manually when it does. I'm just a novice regarding VPNs!

Comment: If you're behind CGNAT, forwarding ports from your router won't accomplish anything